# Global name is not defined for second unittest

Tags: python, eclipse, python-unittest

Eclipse platform, Python 3.3.

I've created the code below to demonstrate a problem when using global variables and python unittest. I'd like to know why the second unit test (a direct repeat of the first) results in a

```
NameError: global name '_fred' is not defined
```

try commenting out the second test and it'll all pass ok.
(Note: I've added a brief digest of what the real code is is attempting to achieve after the example, hopefully it'll be less obtrusive there as it's not really relevant to the issue)

```python
''' Global Problem
'''
import unittest

_fred = None

def start():
    global _fred
    if _fred is None:
        _fred = 39
    _fred += 3

def stop():
    global _fred
    if _fred is not None:
        del _fred

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        start()

    def tearDown(self):
        stop()

    def test_running_first_time(self):
        assert(_fred == 42)

    def test_running_second_time(self):
        assert(_fred == 42)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #import sys;sys.argv = ['', 'Test.testName']
    unittest.main()
```

In the real code _fred is variable referencing an instance of a class derived from Thread (see what I did there) and gets assigned in the start method.
    _fred = MyThreadClass()
There is a second global for a synchronized queue.
The methods start and stop control processing queue items on the dedicated thread. 'stop' stops the processing while allowing items to be added.
The API for Thread only permits a single call to start. So to restart processing I need a new instance of Thread. Hence the use of

```
if _fred is None:
```

and

```
del _fred
```

No prizes for guessing my primary language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`del _fred` does not set `_fred` to `None` or anything like that. It removes the name `_fred`. Completely. For a global, it's as if it had never existed. For a local, it's as if it had never been assigned to. To set a variable to `None`, do the obvious thing:

```
_fred = None
```

Comment: Ah. Good to know the difference. I used del because I thought it made the code more readable (and I sort of used del like the c/c++ del)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `del _fred`. Since you tell the interpreter `_fred` is global, `_fred` gets removed from the global dictionary, and is not set to `None`. When you tell a function that something is global all it does it remember that so when it performs operations on that variable name it does it globally.  `global _fred` in `start` will not in anyway affect the value of `_fred` even if `_fred` is undefined.  It is just a head's up to the interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

When you do this:

```
def stop():
    global _fred
    if _fred is not None:
        del _fred
```

you're actually accessing this module global variable dictionary, and when fred is not None, you are removing variable *fred from module (it doesn't exists any more). Unit test calls setUp and tearDown for each test* method, and first method's tearDown will remove _fred from modules variable dict, what will lead second setUp to fail.

Probably this is what you want to do:

```
if _fred is not None:
    _fred = None
```

On the other hand, I would prefer putting start and stop to a new class, and make _fred global instance of this class:

```
class Fred:
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = None

    def start(self):
        if self.state is None:
            self.state = 39
        self.state += 3

    def stop(self):
        if self.state is not None:
            self.state = None

_fred = Fred()

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        _fred.start()

    def tearDown(self):
        _fred.stop()

    def test_running_first_time(self):
        self.assertEqual(_fred.state, 42)

    def test_running_second_time(self):
        self.assertEqual(_fred.state, 42)
```

Comment: Tx. Personally I prefer a second class to encapsulate _fred - but in reading around I thought this was not 'pythonic', it being preferred to use module methods/state. Also removes use of 'global'.
As I'm new to python I want to start properly